# transfer values between c and bash

Tags: c, bash

Simple question, I hope

I have a c program that does a lot of math.  It requires a few input floats and then returns a few floats.  I would like this code to be incorporated into a bash script that runs it at the right time and passes it the right value, and then reads the result.

What is the simplest and easiest way to do this?  Would passing these values as a command line argument at the calling of the c program work?  And then simply store the results as a string in bash to be parsed at my convenience?  Please tell me there is an easy way to do that!

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `atod()` and `printf()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass command line arguments to your C program, through [arguments to  `main`](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter10/arguments_to_main.html). In the easiest case, your program returns a single number (result) and you can capture that result back in your bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

...

RESULT=$(mycprogram arg1 arg2)

...
```

Comment: a) I personally tend to think that passing arguments to stdin is more flexible. b) Reading the result from the program's stdout also works for multiple result values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
char * getenv (const char *name)
```

so you'll use something like

```
char *foo = NULL;

foo = getenv("BAR");
```

Keep in mind that you'll get a char* back, so if you're hoping for an `int` you'll need to use `atoi()` or something like it. Same goes for checking it's not NULL.  If you're expecting many variables that you rely on, you could check for everything at the beginning of your program.